# Testing an Azure Function Service Bus Trigger in the Portal with a Brokered Message

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I've created an Azure Function that is using a Service Bus queue trigger to run. It's also using a `BrokeredMessage` as the queue item parameter because I need to get some data out of the custom User Properties of the message.

```
public async static Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myQueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ConnString")]BrokeredMessage queueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    string myProperty = queueItem.Properties["MyProperty"].ToString();
    ... // do stuff
}
```

This all works great and I've deployed it to Azure, but I'd like to test it through the portal. They provide a way to test your function:

[image]

But it just asks for the request body. Is there a way to also add User Properties as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would have to use some custom code or a tool like [ServiceBus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) to send a message with metadata properties.